# what is the difference between using arrow function and not using arrow?(feat.React) [Edited]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I have few examples.

first

```js
const { window } = props;
const container =
    window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;
```

It means if window is not `undefined`, it will show something in the body.
but what's the difference between using below??

```js
const container =
    window !== undefined ? window().document.body : undefined;
```

and secondly
In jsx, I set onChange event and these two work differently.

```js
const handleClick = () => { console.log('hi'); }
<input onChange={handleClick} type="text"/> 
//=> this operates well when input tag value is changed.

<input onChange={()=>handleClick} type="text"/>
//=>it doesn't work even when input tag value is changed.
```

- Edited
  Now I clearly understood the differences.

```html
1. <input onChange={handleClick} type="text"/>
2. <input onChange={() => handleClick()} type="text"/> 
//1,2 work same. But when you have to pass 'event' or some parameters to
//function, you can use second way.

//or If you wanna put more than one functions on `onChage` event,
2-1. <input onChange={() => {handleClick(); handleCheck();}} type="text"/> 

3. <input onChange={handleClick()} type="text"/> 
//This will call function immediately (when component mounted)
// even 'input' tag is not changed.

4. <input onChange={()=> handleClick} type="text"/> 
//This just returns `handleClick` function so `handleClick` will not be operated.
```

Comment: in the first case `container` is a function, in the second it isn't. You don't show where you use `container` so it's hard to say which is "right" - although I don't see an obvious need for this to be a function since I doubt the value ever changes (and if it ever does, in the context of React a rerender and therefore recalculation of `container` should happen automatically).

Comment: as for the `onChange` example at the bottom - `onChange` expects a function which (optionally) takes the event object as an argument. Assuming `handleClick` is such a handler function, then `onChange={handleClick}` is correct, `onChange={()=>handleClick}` does nothing but just returns the handler function, without calling it.

Comment: Now I think I understand your general question - in a nutshell: if `a` is some sort of value, then `() => a` is a function that takes no arguments and always returns `a` while doing nothing else. There's a difference between, say, the number 2 and a function that always returns 2.

Comment: OH I fully understood! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, in:

```
const container =
    window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;
```

the `container` is a function, that you can call to get the value returned by `window().document.body`. But in:

```
const container =
    window !== undefined ? window().document.body : undefined;
```

the `container` is the value returned by `window().document.body`.

It's hard to tell which is correct without context, but the main difference is at which point you read the value of `window().document.body`:

```js
const wVal = {
  document: { body: "A" }
};
const window2 = () => wVal;

const now = window2 !== undefined ? window2().document.body : undefined;
const deffered = window2 !== undefined ? () => window2().document.body : undefined;

window2().document.body = "B";

console.log(now);        //=> "A"
console.log(deffered()); //=> "B"
```

**Secondly**, in:

```
<input onChange={handleClick} type="text"/>
```

`onChange` event will trigger `handleClick` function to be called (with event data as an argument). But in:

```
<input onChange={()=>handleClick} type="text"/>
```

`onChange` event will trigger `()=>handleClick` arrow function to be called, which returns reference to `handleClick` function (without calling it).

Answer (score 0):

> Normal functions created using function declarations or expressions are constructible and callable.
> However, the arrow functions are only callable and not constructible,i.e arrow functions can never be used as constructor functions.
> Hence, they can never be invoked with the new keyword.

```js
//Normal Function
var hello;

hello = function() {
  return "Hello World!";
}



//Arrow Function
var hello;

hello = () => {
  return "Hello World!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular functions and arrow functions have multiple differencies.

#### 1. Syntax

```
// (param1, param2, paramN) => expression
// ES5
var add = function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
};
// ES6
let add = (x, y) => { return x + y };
```

#### 2. Arguments binding

Arrow functions do not have an arguments binding. However, they have access to the arguments object of the closest non-arrow parent function.

#### 3. Use of this keyword

Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own `this`. The value of `this` inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of `this` in the closest non-arrow parent function.

Find more at this [link](https://betterprogramming.pub/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256)

Or you could find more explication [on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=arrow%20function%20vs%20normal%20function&oq=arrow%20function%20vs%20&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0i20i263j0l7.5304j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score -2):

This article https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/
will give you a better understanding of arrow functions and regular functions then you can put that in react native context.

Secondly: the second OnChange event on the input field didn't work because you have already been decleared as a function

The first OnChange work because you are calling the handleClick decleared

Comment: the question isn't asking about the difference between arrow functions and regular functions (although I initially also expected from the title that it would be asking that)

Comment: I understood that the question wasn't about the difference but to handle the question from a broader perspective firstly he has to understand arrow functions and regular functions then he can know when and why it's used in React Native